# How to get access to "str_match_all" results in R?

Tags: r, string, dimensions

Just used "str_match_all" as follows:

```
a <- str_match_all(dd, '\\d+(\\w+)')`
```

and obtained the following:

```
#[[1]]
#     [,1]      [,2]   
#[1,] "12hours" "hours"
#[2,] "23days"  "days"
```

How can I access each string?

I have tried a[1][,1] to access the first column for example but I get an error saying the number of dimensions is not correct.

Comment: Would you please add a reproducible example to produce your output?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are having trouble accessing each individual element.

I think you have to remember that your output is a list and the element in that list is a matrix. Therefore to access each individual element you first have to invoke which element of the list you are interested in and then the row and then the column.

```
a[[1]][1,2]
```

So in your case, this will access the first element in your list (looks like you only have 1), and then the 1st row and then the 2nd column so it will give you, "hours".

If however, you're more used to working with dataframes as I assume that is your end goal, I would approach this programmatically as follows:

Taking an example from the `str_match_all()` documentation

```
# Creating reproduceable example
strings <- c("Home: 219 733 8965.  Work: 229-293-8753 ",
             "banana pear apple", "595 794 7569 / 387 287 6718")
phone <- "([2-9][0-9]{2})[- .]([0-9]{3})[- .]([0-9]{4})"
```

Your goal is to convert the matrix in to a data frame. Which you do as follows

```
as.data.frame(a[[1]])
```

For future reference, lets say your output is more than 1 element as is the case in this example, you should approach the solution like so:

```
# Make a function that accepts your list variable. 
# Copy and paste the step before and then add an extra step using dplyr::bind_rows()

output_to_df <- function(x){
   a <- as.data.frame(x)
   bind_rows(a)
}
```

```
# Using this function we will then use map_dfr() 
# so that we can apply our premade function on all elements
# of our list no matter how many elements it contains

str_output <- map_df(a, output_to_df)
```

You can now reuse your output_to_df() function as many times as you need.